# problems running SSIS routine from command line

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dtexec

Can't run SSIS package from commend line

tried all the locations of DTExec.exe on machine

I have a basic SSIS package that reads files and loads into database. (runs fine from SSDT)

tried the following command lines :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File "C:\test_ssis\importStuff.dtsx"

<i belive this is the installation for SSDT, but could be wrong!!>

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File "C:\test_ssis\importStuff.dtsx"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File "C:\test_ssis\importStuff.dtsx"                             
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File "C:\test_ssis\importStuff.dtsx"                             
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File "C:\test_ssis\importStuff.dtsx"
```

which correspond to all the locations i could find DTExec on the computer

running first commmand line gives:

```
Started:  15:16:56
Error: 2019-09-02 15:16:58.02
   Code: 0xC001F02A
   Source: Load Full PLU Files
   Description: Cannot create a task from XML for task "get header info", type "Microsoft.ScriptTask" due to error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".
End Error
Error: 2019-09-02 15:16:58.03
   Code: 0xC0010018
   Source: get header info
   Description: Failed to load task "get header info", type "". The contact information for this task is "".
End Error
Error: 2019-09-02 15:16:58.32
   Code: 0xC0040019
   Source: load full updates load full updates (SSIS.Pipeline)
   Description: Data Flow objects cannot be loaded. Check if Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineXml.dll is properly registered.
End Error
Error: 2019-09-02 15:16:58.32
   Code: 0xC0010018
   Source: load full updates
   Description: Failed to load task "load full updates", type "SSIS.Pipeline.7". The contact information for this task is "Performs high-performance data extraction, transformation and loading;Microso
ft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1".
End Error
Error: 2019-09-02 15:16:58.40
   Code: 0xC0010026
   Source: get header info
   Description: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "".
End Error
Error: 2019-09-02 15:16:58.42
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: get header info
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
Error: 2019-09-02 15:16:58.42
   Code: 0xC0010025
   Source: importHQFullExtract
   Description: The package cannot execute because it contains tasks that failed to load.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  15:16:56
Finished: 15:16:58
Elapsed:  1.997 seconds

all the others give somethign like :

Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 15.0.1301.433 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Started:  15:53:53
Could not create DTS.Application because of error 0x80040154
Started:  15:53:53
Finished: 15:53:53
Elapsed:  0.016 seconds
```

I think some googling implied that both these seemed to be something to do with the version?

but I am confused as surely ONE of these must conform to the one that came with SSDT?

when I do 'help about' in SSDT line is the correct one?

any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: SSDT only allows running packages in Visual Studio.  Running from the command line requires SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you SQL Server version is the same as Visal Studio. I use version 2019 and correct version is 150.

Just instal file: SQL2019-SSEI-Expr available on Microsoft page or other wchis is properly for your version.

Then change:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe"